# Spark : Control partitioning to reduce shuffle

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, partitioning

I'm trying to wrap my head around the different ways of `partitioning` a dataframe in Spark in order to reduce the amount of shuffling on a specific pipeline.

Here is the dataframe I'm working on, it contains 4+ billions rows and 80 columns:

```
+-----+-------------------+-----------+
|  msn|          timestamp| Flight_Id |
+-----+-------------------+-----------+
|50020|2020-08-22 19:16:00|       72.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:15:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:14:00|       96.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:13:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:12:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:11:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:10:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:09:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:08:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:07:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:06:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:05:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:04:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:03:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:02:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:01:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 19:00:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 18:59:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 18:58:00|       84.0|
|50020|2020-08-22 18:57:00|       84.0|
+-----+-------------------+-----------+
```

This represent a collection of time series for different aircraft (41 aircrafts in total).
I'm only doing two things on this data :

1. Filter to keep the last 30 min of each flight using a window partitioned by `MSN` and `Flight_ID` and using an `order By` by `timestamp`.
2. On the remaining columns, compute `mean` and `stdev` and normalize the data.

I have 32 executors with 12g of memory each and the job has crashed after running for 30 hours with the following message :

```
The driver running the job crashed, ran out of memory, or otherwise became unresponsive while it was running.
```

Looking at the Query Plan I noticed I have over 300 steps, more than 60 of them involving a shuffling (all steps Physical plan looks exactly the same):

```
AdaptiveSparkPlan(isFinalPlan=false)
+- CollectLimit 1
   +- HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[avg(3546001_421#213), stddev_samp(3546001_421#213)], output=[avg(3546001_421)#10408, stddev_samp(3546001_421)#10417])
      +- Exchange SinglePartition, true
         +- HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_avg(3546001_421#213), partial_stddev_samp(3546001_421#213)], output=[sum#10479, count#10480L, n#10423, avg#10424, m2#10425])
            +- Project [3546001_421#213]
               +- Filter (isnotnull(rank#10238) && (rank#10238 <= 1800))
                  +- Window [rank(timestamp#10081) windowspecdefinition(Flight_Id_Int#209, timestamp#10081 DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS rank#10238], [Flight_Id_Int#209], [timestamp#10081 DESC NULLS LAST]
                     +- Sort [Flight_Id_Int#209 ASC NULLS FIRST, timestamp#10081 DESC NULLS LAST], false, 0
                        +- ShuffleQueryStage 0
                           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Flight_Id_Int#209, 200), true
                              +- Union
                                 :- *(1) Project [Flight_Id_Int#209, cast((cast(timestamp#212L as double) / 1.0E9) as timestamp) AS timestamp#10081, 3546001_421#213]
```

I have a strong feeling that partitioning first by `msn` would help in reducing the amount of shuffling since most of the work is at the `msn` level.

**My question are** **How** and **Where** in my code I should repartition ? Should I use `repartition`, `repartition` with a key, `hash partitioning` I've been reading documentation on this different Partitioner and I'm confuse about their use and if that's actually the solution to my problem.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the logical plan :

```
GlobalLimit 1
+- LocalLimit 1
   +- Aggregate [avg(3566000_421#214) AS avg(3566000_421)#10594, stddev_samp(3566000_421#214) AS stddev_samp(3566000_421)#10603]
      +- Project [3566000_421#214]
         +- Filter (isnotnull(rank#10238) && (rank#10238 <= 1800))
            +- Window [rank(timestamp#10081) windowspecdefinition(msn#208, Flight_Id_Int#209, timestamp#10081 DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS rank#10238], [msn#208, Flight_Id_Int#209], [timestamp#10081 DESC NULLS LAST]
               +- Union
                  :- Project [msn#208, Flight_Id_Int#209, cast((cast(timestamp#212L as double) / 1.0E9) as timestamp) AS timestamp#10081, 3566000_421#214]
```

Here is the section of the code where I pull the data together from the data lake they are stored in.
FYI, this is done through a custom API using a library called `FoundryTS`. The important thing is that nothing in term of data is colleced until I call the `to_dataframe()` method. I'm looping over each `msn` to avoid making a call too big and then I merge all the dataframe together with `unionByName`

```
# Loop over MSN to extract timeseries
        df = []
        for msn in msn_range:
            search_results = (SeriesMetadata.M_REPORT_NUMBER == report_number) & (SeriesMetadata.M_AIRCRAFT == msn)

            # Create the intervals to split TimeSeries extract by flight for each MSN
            Start_int = list(df1.where(F.col("msn") == msn).select("Start").toPandas()["Start"])
            End_int = list(df1.where(F.col("msn") == msn).select("End").toPandas()["End"])
            flight_id = list(df1.where(F.col("msn") == msn).select("id_cmsReport").toPandas()["id_cmsReport"])

            flights_interval = [Interval(
                start, end, name=flight_Id
                ) for start, end, flight_Id in zip(
                Start_int, End_int, flight_id
                )]

            """ Collect all the series in a node collections """
            output = fts.search.series(
                search_results,
                object_types=["export-control-us-ear99-a220-dal-airline-series"])\
                .map_by(FF.interpolate(
                    before='nearest',
                    internal='nearest',
                    after='nearest',
                    frequency=frequency,
                    rename_columns_by=lambda x: x.metadata["parameter_id"] + "_" + x.metadata["report_number"]),
                    keys='msn') \
                .map_intervals(flights_interval, interval_name='Flight_Id_Int')\
                .map(FF.time_range(period_start, period_end))\
                .to_dataframe()  # !!!!  numPartitions=32  Foundry Doc : #partition = #executors see if it triggers OOM error

            df.append(output)

        output = df[0]
        for df in df[1:]:
            output = output.unionByName(df)  # Same as union but matches name instead of columns order.

        # Repartition by msn to improve latter calculation
        N = len(msn_range)
        output.repartition(N, 'msn')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those it might help,

Here are the things I got wrong in the partitioning :

1. `.to_dataframe()` : by default in our cloud platform Spark create 200 partitions. So by looping over the 40 `msn` I was generating 40 x 200 partition. I ended up with a lot of small task to manage.
2. `.repartition()` : Since I was using a `Window` and `partitionBy` on `msn` I though re partitioning using `msn` will speed up this step. But it introduced a full shuffle of my partitions.

results: 59 GB of shuffle write according to Spark Job Tracker and > 55k tasks. Task taking some overhead this would explain the driver crashing.

What I did to make it work :

1. I got rid of the `Window` function

By filtering earlier in the process before I fetch the data from the DataLake. I directly extracted for the part of the flight I needed. As a consequence, less `Exchange Partition` in the Physical plan for the exact same section.

Here is the updated Physical plan:

```
AdaptiveSparkPlan(isFinalPlan=false)
+- CollectLimit 1
   +- HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[avg(3565000_421#213), stddev_samp(3565000_421#213)], output=[avg(3565000_421)#10246, stddev_samp(3565000_421)#10255])
      +- ShuffleQueryStage 0
         +- Exchange SinglePartition, true
            +- *(43) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_avg(3565000_421#213), partial_stddev_samp(3565000_421#213)], output=[sum#10317, count#10318L, n#10261, avg#10262, m2#10263])
               +- Union
                  :- *(1) Project [3565000_421#213]
                  :  +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[msn#208,Flight_Id_Int#209,Flight_Id_Int.start#210L
```

2. I decreased the amount of partition:

I set it arbitrarily to 5 in the `.to_dataframe()` call for each of the 40 `msn`.

The build succeeded after 24h. 1.1MB of Shuffle write and >27 Tasks.

As @Andrew Long pointed out, it's probably sub-optimal due to the `for` loop. I'm still generating at least 200 partitions for 32 executors, ending up with > 27k Tasks to manage.

**Finally:**

As a last step I got rid of the for loop by relying on the underlying API to fetch the data in 1 big dataframe instead and a forced the partition to 32.
Build is still running as of this writing and I will edit the post with the result.
But there is indeed way less Tasks to manage (by a factor 4).

**EDIT 1 - update**

Happy to report that by getting rid of the for loop and partitioning the dataframe in 64 partitions (32 executors x 2 cores) I was able to pull the same job in only 11h (instead of 24h) with 1.9MB of Shuffle write and 5k Tasks only.

PS: I mentioned 32 (and not 64) partitions above, but the job did not succeed with 32 and had sub-optimal parallelism (< 20) so it was tooking longer and I had idle executors. 64 in my case seems to be the sweet spot.

Answer (score 1):

"The driver running the job crashed, ran out of memory, or otherwise became unresponsive while it was running."

The first problem you need to fix is to bump up the memory of the driver (not the executors.  The default driver mem in spark is oftentimes so low it will crash on many queries.

"My question are How and Where in my code I should repartition"

Spark already does the job of adding repartitions as necessary.  Chances are you will only create extra work by manually repartitioning the data halfway through execution.  One potential optimization is to store the data in a bucketed table but that will only potentially remove the first exchange and only if your bucketing column exactly matches the hash partitioning of the first exchange.

"Looking at the Query Plan I noticed I have over 300 steps"

What you described above does not take 300 steps.  Something seems off here.  What does your optimized logical plan look like?  mean and std should only require a scan -> partitial agg -> exchange -> final agg.  In the query plan you provided it looks like you're intentionally only looking at the last 1600 datapoints instead of the last 30m.  Did you mean todo a window function and not a simple aggregate(aka group by)?

EDIT:

> for msn in msn_range:

IMO this might be a part of your problem.  This for loop causes the execution plan to be very large which may be why you're geting OOM issues on the driver.  you might be able to translate this into something thats a bit more spark friendly and doesn't do as much work on the driver converting that forloop into a spark.paralellize(...).map(/*your code*/)

Comment: Thanks, I've already maxed out the amount of memory on the driver with my level of permission on the cloud platform.
When I say 300 steps, I mean that the query plan I showed you is just an extract. This exact plan is repeated more than 60 times In the Query plan. I will Edit this post to add the Logical Plan associated with this step.
I'm looking at 1800 data point since I have 1 point by second on the real data set. So 30m = 1800s.

Comment: about 'repartition' I'm going to add the section of the code relevant to this section in the post. I was hoping that shuffling to get partition by msn would reduce the workload later on when my Window function and partition by msn.
Wat do you mean by bucketed table ? How do you do that ?

Comment: can you replace the window function with WHERE timestamp > '...' AND timestamp < '...' ?

Comment: also whats your driver memory set to atm?

Comment: driver memory is 13g, I've tried getting rid of the Window, instead I moved the filter for the last 30min up in the 'flights_interval'. So instead of extracting 4B rows of flight, group by flight and sort by timestamp  to filter, I'm directly filtering for the right period when collecting the data. As a result I have one less Exchange Partition. It's been running for 4h still going.

Comment: just saw your EDIT. I'm going to try this once my current build is done. I though using a for loop would increase parallelism since each loop are independent of each other, isn't that the case ?

Comment: too much parallelism can cause performance issues all on its own due to increasing the number of things that the driver needs to track which is probably the source of your memory issue on the driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224421/discussion-between-yoan-b-and-andrew-long).